# About the closure of a commutative subgroup of a topological group.

Tags: topological-groups

Let $H$ a topological subgroups of  a topological group $G$, and $H'$ the closure of $H$ as topological subspace. 
Are classic results the if $H'$ is a topological subgroup, and that it is normal if $H$ is normal this for a general topological group, and that if $G$ is topologically $T_2$ then $H'$ is commutative if $H$ is commutative.
All these results are for example from "Topology I" of Bourbaki.
But in literature nothing about the closure of a commutative subgroup if the topology is (more) general, and is not even a counterexample.

I ask a for a such counterexample, or for a more general condition about the commutativity of the closure of a commutative subgroup.

Comment: I removed the algebraic-groups tag which does not seem relevant

Comment: Take a noncomutative group equipped with concrete topology.

Comment: $aba^{-1}b^{-1}$ is a continuous function on a topological group cross itself, thus the set where it vanishes is closed, so if it vanishes on a set then it vanishes on the closure.

Comment: This requires T1.

Comment:  Yemon Choi: I put the "algebraic-groups-tag" because I thinked about the Zariski Topology of algebraic group.

 

Answer (score 4):

Since the question has been answered in the comments I just repeat it here as a CW answer. Take any infinite non-abelian group with the indiscrete (which I assume is what Anton means by concrete) topology and take the closure of the identity.